# Laravel - Creating a Dynamic URL using a Database String

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I am with a bit of a stuggle here. I managed to create the dynamic URL using the following code:

*Home Page Controller*

```
$satellites = DB::table('satellites')->get();
return view('pages/home', ['satellites' => $satellites]);
```

*Blade File*

```
@foreach($satellites as $satellite)
    <a href="{{$satellite->norad_cat_id}}"><li>{{$satellite->satname}}</li></a>
@endforeach
```

*web.php*

```
Route::get('{norad_cat_id}', 'Satellite@show');
```

*Controller*

```
public function show($norad_cat_id)
{
    return view('pages/satellite');
}
```

The URL generated is: mysite.com/12345 (where 12345 is the norad_cat_id).

This code manages to create the dynamic URLs using the norad_cat_id from the database - which is what I want. The problem is that I can replace the URL with anything and it still creates a page (ie. replace the 12345 with something not from the database and a page is still created).

What I want is only for a URL to be generated only with the norad_cat_id and if there is no matching norad_cat_id in the database, display a 404 page.

Comment: well you just take any norad_cat_id and render the page. you should actually load the object from the database and pass it to the template. laravel can also check if the ID actually exists. look it up in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the show method add a fetch from database if there is no record just abort

```
public function show($norad_cat_id)
{
    $satellite = DB::table('satellites')->where('norad_cat_id', $norad_cat_id)->first();
    if( ! satellite){
        return abort(404);
    }
    return view('pages/satellite');
}
```

PS: abort will automatically redirect to your resources/views/errors/404.blade.php

Answer (score 1):

You can do this multiple ways

1. Create a regex for **norad_cat_id**

The example shows nummeric (`[0-9]+`)

```
Route::get('{norad_cat_id}', 'Satellite@show')->where(['norad_cat_id' => '[0-9]+']);
```

2. Use `findOrFail()` and on fail show the 404.

   ```
   try
   {
       $user = Satellites::findOrFail($id);
        return view('norad_cats');
   }
   // catch(Exception $e) catch any exception
   catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
   {
       return view('404');
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can throw 404 in your controlller (for example). Just check if records exists in database - if not then return error.

**Example:**

```
public function show($cat_id)
{
    $sattelites = DB::table('sattelites')->where('norad_cat_id', $cat_id)->get();

    if ($satellites === NULL)
    {
        \App::abort(404);
    }

    return view('pages/sattelite', [
        'satellites' => $satellites
    ]);
}
```

I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using query builder which is what I assume you're using:

```
public function show($norad_cat_id)
{
    $norad_cat_data = DB::table('satellites')->where('norad_cat_id', $norad_cat_id)->get();

    if (!is_null($norad_cat_id) 
    {
       return view('pages/satellite');
    }
    \App::abort(404);
}
```